# I cant find how to write many mutiple names at once

Tags: python

i wanted to ask the person to write down the names for a lesson but I dont know how to ask him/her all at once and store them as different values. This is my code:

```
print("welcome to the tip calculator :D")
bill = float(input("what was the total bill £: "))
tip = float(input("what percentage tip would you like to give 10? 12? 15? More?: "))
people = float(input(" how many people to split the tip: "))
name_1 = input("what is the name")
msg = bill * (tip / 100) / people
new_msg = round(msg, 2)
new_msg = "{:.2f}".format(msg)
print(f"each of you should pay £{new_msg}")
```

I wanted to add this:

```
input(write down the names of the people)
print(f"{name_1} pays {new_msg}, {name_2} pays {new_msg}
```

but I dont know how to.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Hint: use a list (`[]`). Either have the user enter all names at once, for example separated by a space, and split that string into a list. Or, ask for the number of people as you do, and then loop as many times as the user entered, ask for a name and append it to the list.

Comment: `people` should probably be an `int`, not a `float`. Then you can use that variable to create a [loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) to read the names, and maybe store them in a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code you want is something along the lines of

```
print("Welcome to the tip calculator :D")
bill = float(input("What was the total bill £: "))
ip = float(input("What percentage tip would you like to give (10, 12, 15, or more)?: "))
people = float(input("How many people to split the bill?: "))

names = []
for i in range(int(people)):
    name = input(f"Enter the name of person {i+1}: ")
    names.append(name)

msg = bill * (tip / 100) / people
new_msg = round(msg, 2)
new_msg = "{:.2f}".format(msg)

print(f"\nEach person should pay £{new_msg}")
for name in names:
    print(f"{name} pays £{new_msg}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).